# The Update-Database Add-Migration loop

Tags: entity-framework, entity-framework-migrations

I thought I figured it out when I disabled AutomaticMigrations.

I Update-Database then
Add new column name to DAL class.

Then execute Add-Migration

But I am caught in a loop of nonsense.

I execute Update-Database and am treated to ...
Applying explicit migrations: [a list of the current migrations].

then this line for each migration.
Applying explicit migration: [id]

Then it warning me that the model is NOT up to date.
So I execute Add-Migration
and get the error...
Unable to generate an explicit migration because the following explicit migrations are pending: [the same list I just saw applied]

WTF?

Comment: I resolved this through the following steps.

1) Delete the database file your DAL project is updating.
2) Remove the offending migration. // Comment out the offending column or table.
3) execute Update-Database.
4) Uncomment changes.
5) Add-Migration
6) Update-Database
7) Runtime check.
8) Check-in

Comment: +1 "...caught in a loop of nonsense." That resonated with me.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I resolved this through the following steps.

1. Delete the dataabase file your DAL project is updating.
2. Remove the offending migration. // Comment out the offending column or table.
3. Execute Update-Database.
4. Uncomment changes.
5. Add-Migration
6. Update-Database
7. Runtime check.
8. Check-in

Good luck if you run into this problem.

I further ran into problems when I added code that explicitly called the initializer to speed up startup time.  Then whenever I did an update-database...it would use my context class, try to do the initializer and fail.

Code-First is a good step in the right direction but it has all these be careful scenarios.